# Best option for creating a simple GUI that allows for CSS styling

Tags: java, css, swing, user-interface, hta

I'm trying to create a client-side GUI that has 4 buttons and an open file dialog box. I've been trying Java Swing for a few days and can't figure out if CSS styling is possible.

Previously I've been using a .hta file as a GUI since I can use my javascript, html and CSS knowledge. Plus I can easily create a .hta from a text file.

But with Swing it seems I need to compile into a .jar and then use JSmooth or similar to convert to .exe. But I'm turned off from the fact that other people using my GUI will require Javascript to be installed in order to run the jar or exe, whereas the. HTA GUI runs regardless. I understand HTAs are old and so I'm looking for an alternative.

What's the best way to create a simple GUI that I can design using CSS, and that will have minimal obstacles for end users? The buttons will only be writing to text files, very basic.

The buttons I'm trying to style can be [found here.](http://codepen.io/colewaldrip/pen/bdZVGd)

Thanks for your help.

Snippet:

```
  .main-wrapper {
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 20px;
            box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
            position: relative;
    }

    i.material-icons {
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            color: white;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 3px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
            transition: color 0.2s ease, background-color 0.2s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
    }
i.material-icons:after {
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: solid 2px;
        transform: scale(0.8);
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        left: -2px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

i.material-icons:hover:after {
        transform: scale(1);
        box-shadow: 10px 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 6px 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

i.material-icons:nth-of-type(4) {
        background-color: #88b999;
}
```

Comment: JavaFX allows CSS styling.

Comment: Sounds perfect! Thank you